# Android PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs and webview

Tags: android, eclipse, string, webview, pagerslidingtabstrip

I downloaded [Pager Sliding Tab Strip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip) sample from GitHub.  I want to create a `WebView`.  For example tap Home to bring me to my homepage and tap Top Paid to go to my Forum?Sorry for my newbie question but i am new to this :). Thanks

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final String[] TITLES = { "Categories", "Home", 
            "Top Paid", "Top Free", "Top Grossing", "Top New Paid",
            "Top New Free", "Trending" };

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return TITLES[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return TITLES.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return SuperAwesomeCardFragment.newInstance(position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `PagerSlidingTabStrip` is not supposed to work with a `WebView`, usually you use it in conjunction with a `ViewPager`.

For what you want to achieve - *"when tap Home to bring me to my homepage when tap Top Paid to go to my Forum"* - it seems you are talking about a web app. If this is so, then `PagerSlidingTabStrip` can't help you with this, you'll have to use the web tools (HTML/CSS) to develop the tabs, just like you would build them for a regular web page.

On the other hand if you are looking for something like [this](https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2013/08/21/example-using-viewpager-with-actionbarsherlock-tabs/), then you'll have to take a look at the [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) and [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) (or PagerSlidingTabStrip).

Comment: Thanks Andy.

I want when scroll to Top Paid for example to show Google.com for example.This is not possible for PageSlidingTabStrip?If it possible please someone show the code for that i will be very grateful.

Comment: You could use `PagerSlidingTabStrip` in conjunction with a `ViewPager`, and for every page of ViewPager display a `WebView` that will load a specific web page. That is possible.